# Make url pretty with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to adopt the following scheme:

1. If the url contains any file/script reference, leave that without rewriting

   ```
   example.com/index.php ---> leave without rewriting url
   ```
2. If the url doesn't contains any references, something similar to:

   ```
   example.com/some-thing-is-here
   ```

   **Re-write this to:**

   ```
   example.com?search.php?q=some-thing-is-here
   ```

I've found the solution for (1), but they all fail with (2). I am a newbie in htaccess, so need suggestions of how to do it, or a common general method to do it.

Comment: so many similar questions asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you ask. In addition to excluding files, it also excludes directories.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/search.php?q=$1 [R,L]
```

[This article](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls) has some good information if you want to learn more about clean URLs.

Below are a few more resources if you want to learn more about .htaccess. Usage of this file is fairly complex. Once you know what it is capable of, I recommend you search on Google for the features you need, when you need them. There are a lot of things it does that you may never need.

1. [more .htaccess tips and tricks..](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)
2. [Ultimate Htaccess File Sample](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ultimate-htaccess-file-sample.html)
3. [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, please consider selecting it as best answer. Thanks.